# Can you use Google Docs as the text editor for your own application?

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api, rich-text-editor, google-drive-realtime-api

I know Google Drive has an API. Is there a way to use it to essentially use Google Docs as the rich text editor for an application? I.e. I would like to be able to do the following:

1. Create a document.
2. Edit a document as normal, but embedded within my application.
3. Save a document.

Comment: Do you specifically want to integrate with Google, or do you just want rich text editing in your application?

Answer (score 0):

If you embed a browser in your app, I think this is doable if you can get users google accounts and you can follow the google auth api.